Why is there no rows for 'SHOW config_file' in PostgreSQL database?
I have logged into the PostgreSQL db with psql and want to see the location of config file.
But when I execute SHOW config_file, nothing shows up!
[postgres@bddb06 ~]$ psql -U postgres -d postgres
psql (15.8)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# 
postgres=# select datname from pg_database;
  datname  
-----------
 postgres
 template1
 template0
(3 rows)

postgres=# select current_database();
 current_database 
------------------
 postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# 
postgres=# select version();
                                                     version                                                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 15.8 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22.0.1), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# SHOW CONFIG_FILE
postgres-# SHOW 'CONFIG_FILE'
postgres-# SHOW 'config_file'
postgres-# 

Can anyone help?

SHOW commands generally need to end with a semicolon, not just a newline.

Steps to Check:

Ensure you have Super User Privileges

Try another query:
SELECT sourcefile FROM pg_file_settings WHERE name = 'config_file';



If those two steps are failed, then you can check it manually:
The postgresql.conf file is typically found in the data directory specified during the PostgreSQL installation.
Ref - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-file-locations.html
